# Get Json from URL and log it to txt file

Tags: json, bash

I have a link that will output some json when I browse to it in a web browser, and I get a json response like this: `{"totalClients":6514}`. Is there a bash script I can use to put the number of "total clients" into a txt file every minute?

Comment: what do you mean ? what do you want exactly to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you mean by graph the data?
You could use any number of libraries to create a graph
on a html page and use AJAX to load the json data into the javascript.